# Why is this cast from interface to class failing?

Tags: c#, casting

```
private Vector2 ResolveCollision(ICollidable moving, ICollidable stationary)
{
    if (moving.Bounds.Intersects(stationary.Bounds))
    {
        if (moving is Player)
        {
            (Player)moving.Color = Color.Red;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

I have a class `Player` that implements `ICollidable`. For debugging purposes I'm just trying to pass a bunch of `ICollidables` to this method and do some special stuff when it's the player. However when I try to do the cast to `Player` of the `ICollidable` I get an error telling me that `ICollidable` doesn't have a `Color` property.

Am I not able to make a cast this way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just a case of parantheses wrong: `((Player)moving).Color = ...`

Comment: you should say ((Player)moving).Color = Color.Red if Color is an attribute of Player

Comment: My new problem is how I decide which answer to accept. I can never fault this site for being slow...

Comment: you should flip about 3 coins to figure that out.

Comment: though you may have to do this many times as there are only 6 answers and 8 possibilities..aah..sure..just roll a dice

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd suggest using `as` instead of `is`:

```
Player player = moving as Player;
if (player != null)
{
    player.Color = Color.Red;
}
```

The advantage is that you only do the type check once.

---

The specific reason why your code doesn't work (as mentioned in other answers) is because of [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx). The `.` operator is a *primary operator* which has a higher precedence than the casting operator which is a *unary operator*. Your code is interpreted as follows:

```
(Player)(moving.Color) = Color.Red;
```

Adding the parentheses as suggested by other answers solves this issue, but changing to use `as` instead of `is` makes the issue go away completely.

Answer (score 9):

Your syntax is casting `Color` to `Player`, not `moving`.

```
((Player)mover).Color = Color.Red;
//^do the cast  ^access the property from the result of the cast
```

Also, `as` tends to be a little nicer. If it fails, the result is `null`:

```
var player = moving as Player;
if(player != null)
{
    player.Color = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: `is` and then a cast is virtually identical to `as` and then a null check.  In neither case will an exception be thrown.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that it's not working, it's the syntax that is "somewhat" wrong.

Try this:

```
((Player) moving).Color = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add additional brackets:

```
((Player)moving).Color = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses around the cast and the variable:

```
((Player)moving).Color = Color.Red;
```

otherwise you're trying to cast `moving.Color` to `Player`.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten one bracket:

change

```
 (Player)moving.Color = Color.Red;
```

to

```
 ((Player)moving).Color = Color.Red;
```

You can also use the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to cast.

```
Player p = moving as Player;
if (p != null)
{
    p.Color = Color.Red;
}
```